# alternatives to Hash#index that works without warning in both Ruby 1.8 and 1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I've got some ruby code that I'm converting to Ruby 1.9.  One warning I get is `Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key`

But Hash#key is not defined in Ruby 1.8, so I can't use that directly.  Does anybody have a good alternative?

I've got a couple of options (which I'll post as answers so you can vote), but I'm hoping for better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also invert the hash:

```
{ :hello => :world }.invert[:world]    # ==> :hello
```

No monkey-patching or external dependencies, but probably less efficient for most purposes.

Comment: A little late to fix my code now, but my hashes are small so I probably would have used your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another choice is to monkeypatch:

```
class Hash
  alias_method(:key, :index) unless method_defined?(:key)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'backports/1.9.1/hash/key'
{:hello => :world}.key(:world)  # ==> :hello on all ruby versions
```

My [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem defines all of Ruby 1.8.7 and many Ruby 1.9 / 2.0 methods. This makes it much easier to have code that works on all of these platforms.

Comment: you meant `{:hello => :world}.key(:world)`, I hope?  Relying on a commonly-used library to monkey patch is probably better than monkey-patching randomly in each library.   OTOH, nobody appreciates added depdendencies.

Comment: Oups, yes, indeed. I fixed that, thanks.
My goal is to avoid everyone the trouble of figuring out how to monkey-patch stuff correctly; I (usually) run my implementations against rubyspecs too...

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer.  I actually went with the monkey patch myself, but I had other considerations not listed in the question.  This is probably the right answer for most others.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is:

```
(hash.respond_to?(:key) ? hash.key(t) : hash.index(t))
```

But that's gross and adds overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather ugly, but works too:

```
h = { :a => 1 }
[:key,:index].find{|method| break h.send(method, 1) if h.respond_to?(method) }
```